# Process path shown by ps -ef doesn't exist

Tags: 20.04, bash, java, autostart, solr

I'm in the process of tracing a process that autostarts on my machine so that I can stop it happening. I want to stop it because it's causing port 8983 clash with something else.

```
$ ps -ef | grep solr
```

and get:

```
root       87178   87157  0 14:40 ?        00:00:00 bash /opt/solr/bin/solr start -p 8983 -f
root       87311   87178  0 14:40 ?        00:00:05 java -server -Xss256k -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:SurvivorRatio=4 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:PretenureSizeThreshold=64m -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:CMSMaxAbortablePrecleanTime=6000 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -Xloggc:/opt/solr/example/logs/solr_gc.log -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=18983 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=18983 -DSTOP.PORT=7983 -DSTOP.KEY=solrrocks -Djetty.port=8983 -Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/example/solr -Dsolr.install.dir=/opt/solr -Duser.timezone=UTC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/opt/solr/bin/oom_solr.sh 8983 -jar start.jar
```

But when I look in `/opt`, `solr` directory doesn't exist.

How can I trace what is triggering this process to run?  When I kill it, it starts again on a different pid.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not looking at the parent process via PPID (87157) ?

Comment: @Marco I looked at parent process with `pwdx` and it says`/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/263f9f56e558a5b50b312cc7e855c62c55e6c019d68940e42c1108e7869ae064`

Comment: Yes, you have a container running, with the process inside. `/opt` is only available inside the container.

Comment: I guess it is a docker container, see `man docker`

Comment: @Marco Make this your answer!